# Swift SpriteKit: Use of unresolved identifier "player"?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I try to run an action on a sprite I've set a constant for in `didMoveToView`, I use the same name for it in the `touchesBegan` function and get a "use of unresolved identifier: "player" error. I have another game where I so the exact same thing and it runs perfectly. Need help! Here  is my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var movingGround : MCTGround!
    var fruitGenerator : MCTFruitGen!
    var cloudGenerator: MCTCloudGen!

    var isStarted = false

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "koala_idle")
        player.position = CGPointMake(95, 150)
        addChild(player)

        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        movingGround = MCTGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 20))

        movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height / 4)

        addChild(movingGround)

        fruitGenerator = MCTFruitGen(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
        fruitGenerator.position = view.center

        addChild(fruitGenerator)

        let frames = [
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_idle"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_walk01"),
            SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_walk02"),


        ]

        let duration = 1.5 + drand48() * 1.0

        let move = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame:0.10)
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(duration)
        let rest = SKAction.setTexture(frames[0])
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, rest])

        player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))

        cloudGenerator = MCTCloudGen(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
        cloudGenerator.position = view.center
        addChild(cloudGenerator)
        cloudGenerator.populate(7)
        cloudGenerator.startGeneratingWithSpawnTime(1)
    }


    func start() {
        isStarted = true

        cloudGenerator.startGeneratingWithSpawnTime(1)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event:   UIEvent) {
        jumpPlayer()
        movingGround.start()

        fruitGenerator.startGeneratingFruitEvery(1)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }


    func jumpPlayer() {
        let jumpUpAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 40, duration: 0.5)
        let jumpDownAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -40, duration: 0.5)

        let jumpSequence = SKAction.sequence([jumpUpAction, jumpDownAction])
        player.runAction(jumpSequence) // This is where my error is
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not an error dump. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Im asking how to fix this.

Comment: If you google "use of unresolved identifer swift", you get 47,300 results. If you click on the very first result, it will take you to the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make `player` a class scope variable (property). Declare it not in a function, but a level above.

```
var player: SKSpriteNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    player = SKSpriteNode ...
```

then access it via `player?`. The safest way.

Comment: Every time I declare it outside of a function, my game crashes and I get the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring `player` inside `didMoveToView`. This makes it private to the `didMoveToView` method. All you need to do is move `let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "koala_idle")` to where you declare `movingGround` and the other variables with it.

The beginning your code should look like this:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var movingGround : MCTGround!
var fruitGenerator : MCTFruitGen!
var cloudGenerator: MCTCloudGen!
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "koala_idle")

var isStarted = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    player.position = CGPointMake(95, 150)
    addChild(player)
```

Comment: Ive tried this and I still get the same error. In my last game, I put it in didMoveToView and it worked in every function I put it in.

Comment: It works for me. I am adding what you need to do to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *File Inspector* (right click on the file referenced in the error and select `Show File Inspector`). In *Target Membership* make sure your actual app is selected.

In my case only the Test modules were selected.

So as far as I can tell (I'm new to all this), the referenced file was hidden/unregistered with the *ViewController*.